# Powershell Copy-Item copies the contents of a folder to an existing directory

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, copy, copy-item

I'm trying what I think is a simple folder copy but i'm getting stuck on this one.

I need to copy contents of a folder to an existing Sharepoint directory

Here are my tries

```
$SharepointDirectory = '\\Sharepoint\Dir'

net use $SharepointDirectory /user:domain\user Password

$FolderName = "C:\SourceFolder"

Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderName | Copy-Item -Destination $SharepointDirectory -Recurse -force -WhatIf
```

Or i tried to add * on the folder name

```
    $FolderName = "C:\SourceFolder\*"
```

Both have the same result : `What if: Performing the operation "Copy Directory" on target "Item: C:\SourceFolder Destination: \SourceFolder".`

I don't understand why the destination is \SourceFolder

Because when I try with creating a new folder in the destination like so

```
$SharepointDirectory = '\\content.grp.collab.group\Dir\NewFolder'

net use $SharepointDirectory /user:domain\user Password

$FolderName = "C:\SourceFolder"

Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderName | Copy-Item -Destination $SharepointDirectory -Recurse -force -WhatIf
```

Results : `What if: Performing the operation "Copy Directory" on target "Item: C:\SourceFolder Destination: \\content.grp.collab.group\Dir\NewFolder".`

It's working great but I don't want that new folder on the destination

Hope someone can help, thanks !

Comment: You don't need `Get-ChildItem`. This should be all that's needed: `Copy-Item -Path $FolderName\* -Destination $SharepointDirectory -Recurse -Force -WhatIf`. See also examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.3#example-2-copy-directory-contents-to-an-existing-directory

Comment: Yes I already try without Get-ChildItem, allways same results the copy is made in C: at the root

Comment: Does the destination folder exist before you execute the copy-Item command?  If not, you need to create it before the copy.

Comment: As Keith wrote, make sure the destination folder exists: `$null = New-Item $SharepointDirectory -ItemType Directory -Force; Copy-Item -Path $FolderName\* -Destination $SharepointDirectory -Recurse -Force -WhatIf` - this first creates the folder if it does not exist.

Comment: Thanks but the destination folder already exist, that's the thing. As soon as I want to copy on it the copy is made in my C:\ directory for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `copy-item` with a target on sharepoint, or a sharepoint mapped drive, you must fully qualify the target inclusive of file name.

This will work:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcepath\*| Copy-Item -Destination {$SharepointDirectory + $_.Name}
```

Please ask me why this is not documented for Microsoft...-:)